# VLAN trunk to LXD containers

Tags: networking, server, lxc, lxd

I'm playing around w/ LXD containers on Xenial. What I'd like to do is to have an 802.1q trunk coming into my physical host, and have the tagged traffic reach the containers, where I can choose which VLANs to connect to. For example, there's a single trunk carrying VLANs 1, 2 and 3. For container1, I'd like for it to see VLANs 1 and 2, while for container2, it sees VLANs 2 and 3. Any ideas or resources that show how to do this?

So far, I've been able to break out VLANs on the host, so things work at least up to there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 802.1q, but as long as you have the ability to have those VLAN's on separated interfaces on the host, you should be able to add a device on the container with a parent of that VLAN.